# getting problem with working nested json in django framework

Tags: python, django, django-views

Hi Everyone I am trying to writing a code to get nested response based on `driver_id`.

I am not able to solve this issue, kindly help me out.

**views.py**

```
def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        rating= connection.cursor()
        rating.execute(''' SELECT...... ''')
        rating_data=rating.fetchall()
        json_res=[]
        obj={}
        for row in rating_data:
            json_obj=dict(week_start_date=row[0],week_end_date=row[1],driver_id=row[2],driver_name=row[3],mobile=row[4],week_period=row[5],total_trips=row[6],driver_rating=row[7])
            if obj.get('driver_id')==row[2]:
                obj['mobile'].append(json_obj)

            else:
                if obj.get('driver_id')!=None:
                    json_res.append(obj)
                obj={}
                obj['driver_id']=row[2]
                obj['driver_name']=row[3]
                obj['mobile']=[json_obj]
        json_res.append(obj)
        return JsonResponse(json_res,safe=False)
```

**current response**

```
[{'driver_id': 10884,
  'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
  'mobile': [{'driver_id': 10884,
              'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '8348447439',
              'total_trips': 60,
              'week_end_date': '2022-05-15',
              'week_period': 'last week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-05-09'}]},
 {'driver_id': 160,
  'driver_name': 'Mohd Sohail Shaikh',
  'mobile': [{'driver_id': 160,
              'driver_name': 'Mohd Sohail Shaikh',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '7718908984',
              'total_trips': 20,
              'week_end_date': '2022-04-24',
              'week_period': '4th week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-04-18'},
             {'driver_id': 160,
              'driver_name': 'Mohd Sohail Shaikh',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '7718908984',
              'total_trips': 53,
              'week_end_date': '2022-05-15',
              'week_period': 'last week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-05-09'}]},
 {'driver_id': 10884,
  'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
  'mobile': [{'driver_id': 10884,
              'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '8348447439',
              'total_trips': 60,
              'week_end_date': '2022-05-08',
              'week_period': '2nd week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-05-02'}]}]
```

**expected output**

```
[{'driver_id': 10884,
  'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
  'mobile': [{'driver_id': 10884,
              'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '8348447439',
              'total_trips': 60,
              'week_end_date': '2022-05-15',
              'week_period': 'last week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-05-09'},
             {'driver_id': 10884,
              'driver_name': 'Dipankar Mandal',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '8348447439',
              'total_trips': 60,
              'week_end_date': '2022-05-08',
              'week_period': '2nd week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-05-02'}]},
 {'driver_id': 160,
  'driver_name': 'Mohd Sohail Shaikh',
  'mobile': [{'driver_id': 160,
              'driver_name': 'Mohd Sohail Shaikh',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '7718908984',
              'total_trips': 20,
              'week_end_date': '2022-04-24',
              'week_period': '4th week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-04-18'},
             {'driver_id': 160,
              'driver_name': 'Mohd Sohail Shaikh',
              'driver_rating': 'Mediocre',
              'mobile': '7718908984',
              'total_trips': 53,
              'week_end_date': '2022-05-15',
              'week_period': 'last week',
              'week_start_date': '2022-05-09'}]}]
```

> [Diff checker](https://www.diffchecker.com/019kOORl). Old is current, new is expected

Comment: Is there a specific reason for you not to use Django ORM and rest framework? It would've been a lot easier for you

Comment: @ÇağatayBarın yes lots of complax data, that's why i use raw query

Comment: To be honest, without using a serializer and ORM, this code will always look like a mess. Also, your expected output has lots of repetitive data (drive_id, driver_name is repeated in mobile items). I'd suggest you to maybe change the focus of the question from response manipulating to use the best practices for this kind of situation. You can start by adding your query (and explaining what are you trying to do) and your model structure. You can still use raw queries with ORM if you can't manage to get it work with what ORM offers.

Comment: i have solve this query using mysql

Comment: It doesn't matter which database you use. ORM is the manager which abstracts the interactions with the database, and creates the query that suits your database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/